# EF 3.x. eager loading many to many InvalidOperationException MVC

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I need help in **EF 5. eager loading many to many** strange it was used to work in the previous versions < 3.x

throw

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot apply the 'Include' operation with
> argument 'g => g.Attendees'. Either the source is not a queryable of a
> known entity type or 'Include' has been applied after 'Select' method
> which projects a different entity type through navigation. Consider
> applying 'Include' before 'Select' method call.

**and ofcourse without eager loading it gives the normal nullreferenceexception
and no error in the compilation**

*`this used to work on previous EF less than 3.x`*

```
var userid = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

var GigsIamAttending = _context.Attendances.Where(a => a.FollowerId == userid)

.Select(g => g.Gig)

.Include(g => g.Attendees)

.Include(g => g.Genre)

.ToList();

var viewmodel = new UpcommingGigsViewModel()

{

IsAuthorized = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated,

UpComingGigs = GigsIamAttending

};

return View( viewmodel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange this worked for me , I don't know if this will get redundant joins!

```
 var GigsIamAttending = _context.Attendances.Where(a => a.FollowerId == userid)
                .Include(a => a.Gig)
                .ThenInclude(gig => gig.Artist)
                .Include(a => a.Gig)
                .ThenInclude(gig => gig.Genre)
                .Select(a =>a.Gig);

            var viewmodel = new UpcommingGigsViewModel()
            {
                IsAuthorized = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated,
                UpComingGigs = GigsIamAttending
            };
            return View( viewmodel);
```